# Exclude folders from auto-completion analysis in Netbeans or Netbeans auto-completion is slow

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

In my PHP project I have duplicated code folders (That means a lot of duplicated PHP files). When Netbeans shows the auto-completions, the classes and methods shows up as triple (3 same method definitions). Each from different files. I think that makes it slow to show the autocomplete suggestions. It takes like 10 seconds to show the auto-completions.

I want to exclude the duplicated folders from parsing.

My version is 8.1.
I have already used the **Ignored folders for code analysis** option

**Note: don't tell me to delete the duplicated folders. I need them for some reasons.**

Answer (score 1):

- Right click the PHP project in your Projects tree.
- Select`Properties`
- Select `Ignored Folders`

Add the folders with the classes you would like to ignore to the list